# How can I make Material Icons rounded using Icon Font?

Tags: html, css, material-design, google-material-icons

I'm using [Material Icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/) for my website.

To show the icons, I use icon font...

```
<i class="material-icons">arrow_forward</i>
```

If you look on the side of the Material Icons website, you will see that there is an option for 'Rounded' which rounds the edges of the icons...

[image]

The only way I can seem to get it is by downloading it as a file.
Is there a way to get it using Icon Fonts (HTML/CSS)?